# How to add/delete parent node dynamically using button in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a input field dynamically using append child method with add and delete button.
It will create a tree like structure.
On clicking add button it will create a child node with add and delete button.
Again on clicking the add button in child node ,It need to create a sub child node.That I did manually.
But I need to add child and sub child node dynamically(for n numbers).
How to add this dynamically using append child method in java script.

Also on clicking delete button the parent node has to be deleted.
How to get the parent node ID that is generated dynamically?

```js
function add_div(){
      var div1 = document.createElement('ul');
      document.body.appendChild(div1);
      div1.className = 'ui-modal';
      div1.id = 'test-' + document.querySelectorAll('.ui-modal > .msg1').length;
      var  check = div1.id;

      var list = document.createElement('li');

      list.className = 'msg1';
      div1.appendChild(list);

      var input = document.createElement('input');
      list.appendChild(input);
      input.placeholder="parent";

      var button1 = document.createElement('button');
      list.appendChild(button1);

      var t1 = document.createTextNode("ADD");
      button1.appendChild(t1);

      button1.addEventListener("click", add_div2);


      var button2 = document.createElement('button');
      list.appendChild(button2);

      var t2 = document.createTextNode("DEL");
      button2.appendChild(t2);

      button2.addEventListener("click", remove_div);



    function add_div2(){
      var div2 = document.createElement('ul');
      div1.appendChild(div2);

      var lists = document.createElement('li');
      div2.appendChild(lists);
      div2.className = 'sub-div';

      div2.id = 'sub_test-' + document.querySelectorAll('.sub-div > .msg2').length;


      lists.className = 'msg2';
      div2.appendChild(lists);

      var inputs = document.createElement('input');
      lists.appendChild(inputs);
      inputs.placeholder="child";

      var button1s = document.createElement('button');
      lists.appendChild(button1s);

      var t1s = document.createTextNode("ADD");
      button1s.appendChild(t1s);

      button1s.addEventListener("click", add_div3);


      var button2s = document.createElement('button');
      lists.appendChild(button2s);

      var t2s = document.createTextNode("DEL");
      button2s.appendChild(t2s);

      button2s.addEventListener("click", remove_div);

    }
    
    function add_div3(){
      var div3 = document.createElement('ul');
      div1.appendChild(div3);

      var listss = document.createElement('li');
      div3.appendChild(listss);
      div3.className = 'inner-sub-div';

      div3.id = 'sub_test-' + document.querySelectorAll('.inner-sub-div > .msg3').length;


      listss.className = 'msg3';
      div3.appendChild(listss);

      var inputss = document.createElement('input');
      listss.appendChild(inputss);
      inputss.placeholder="sub child";

      var button1ss = document.createElement('button');
      listss.appendChild(button1ss);

      var t1ss = document.createTextNode("ADD");
      button1ss.appendChild(t1ss);

    


      var button2ss = document.createElement('button');
      listss.appendChild(button2ss);

      var t2ss = document.createTextNode("DEL");
      button2ss.appendChild(t2ss);

      button2ss.addEventListener("click", remove_div);

    }

    function remove_div(){
      var check = document.getElementById('test-0');
      check.parentNode.removeChild(check);
    }

  
}
```

```css
.ui-modal{
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
    left:0;
    z-index: 55;
}
.sub-div{
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    left: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 66;
}
.inner-sub-div{
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    left: 250px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 77;

}
.plus{
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="button" value="ADD" onclick="add_div();">
</div>
```

The button is also generated using append child method. Add listener event is added to it.(i.e) while clicking add button the input field gets added with add and delete button.
While clicking add button the node gets added.
But while clicking delete button,I am not able to get the ID.?

I have delete one parent node having id test-0.

```
function remove_div(){
      var check = document.getElementById('test-0');
      check.parentNode.removeChild(check);
    }
```

But I want it to be deleted dynamically.
How to get that particular ID oh the parent node?

All has to be done dynamically?
I have created manually by giving name for each field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to get the correct `ID`,
I suggest you to use the `this` keyword in your `remove_div()`:

Doc about `this`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

See working snippet:

```js
function add_div() {
  var div1 = document.createElement('ul');
  document.body.appendChild(div1);
  div1.className = 'ui-modal';
  div1.id = 'test-' + document.querySelectorAll('.ui-modal > .msg1').length;
  var check = div1.id;

  var list = document.createElement('li');

  list.className = 'msg1';
  div1.appendChild(list);

  var input = document.createElement('input');
  list.appendChild(input);
  input.placeholder = "parent";

  var button1 = document.createElement('button');
  list.appendChild(button1);

  var t1 = document.createTextNode("ADD");
  button1.appendChild(t1);
  button1.addEventListener("click", add_div2);

  var button2 = document.createElement('button');
  list.appendChild(button2);

  var t2 = document.createTextNode("DEL");
  button2.appendChild(t2);

  button2.addEventListener("click", remove_div);
  

  function add_div2() {
    var div2 = document.createElement('ul');
    div1.appendChild(div2);

    var lists = document.createElement('li');
    div2.appendChild(lists);
    div2.className = 'sub-div';

    div2.id = 'sub_test-' + document.querySelectorAll('.sub-div > .msg2').length;

    lists.className = 'msg2';
    div2.appendChild(lists);

    var inputs = document.createElement('input');
    lists.appendChild(inputs);
    inputs.placeholder = "child";

    var button1s = document.createElement('button');
    lists.appendChild(button1s);

    var t1s = document.createTextNode("ADD");
    button1s.appendChild(t1s);

    button1s.addEventListener("click", add_div3);


    var button2s = document.createElement('button');
    lists.appendChild(button2s);

    var t2s = document.createTextNode("DEL");
    button2s.appendChild(t2s);

    button2s.addEventListener("click", remove_div);

  }

  function add_div3() {
    var div3 = document.createElement('ul');
    div1.appendChild(div3);

    var listss = document.createElement('li');
    div3.appendChild(listss);
    div3.className = 'inner-sub-div';

    div3.id = 'sub_test-' + document.querySelectorAll('.inner-sub-div > .msg3').length;

    listss.className = 'msg3';
    div3.appendChild(listss);

    var inputss = document.createElement('input');
    listss.appendChild(inputss);
    inputss.placeholder = "sub child";

    var button1ss = document.createElement('button');
    listss.appendChild(button1ss);

    var t1ss = document.createTextNode("ADD");
    button1ss.appendChild(t1ss);

    var button2ss = document.createElement('button');
    listss.appendChild(button2ss);

    var t2ss = document.createTextNode("DEL");
    button2ss.appendChild(t2ss);

    button2ss.addEventListener("click", remove_div);

  }

  function remove_div() {
    var check = this.closest("ul"); // TAKIT: Suggestion
    check.parentNode.removeChild(check);
  }

}
```

```css
.ui-modal {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 55;
}

.sub-div {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 66;
}

.inner-sub-div {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  left: 250px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 77;
}

.plus {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="button" value="ADD" onclick="add_div();">
</div>
```

Anyway, I feel your whole code can be enhanced, because all your `add_divx()` seem to be similar.

---

⋅
⋅
⋅

So, here is what I'll do to make your code way easier:

- Use HTML to create your different template elements, so that HTML stays in HTML,
- Add a `class` to your template elements and use `display: none;` in its CSS,
- Create only one function to add elements, with parameters.

I also removed your CSS and added only a few lines, just to make the snippet short and visual.

Here is what I ended-up with:

```js
function append(level, elm) {
  if (!elm) elm = document.body;
  else elm = elm.closest('ul');
  var appended = document.querySelector('#temp' + level).children[0].cloneNode(true);
  elm.appendChild(appended);
}

function remove_div(button) {
  var elm = button.closest("ul");
  elm.parentNode.removeChild(elm);
}
```

```css
.templates { display: none; }

ul {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  width: 200px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}

.level1 { border: 2px solid #f88; }
.level2 { border: 2px solid #8f8; }
.level3 { border: 2px solid #88f; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="button" value="ADD" onclick="append(1);">
</div>
<div class="templates" id="temp1">
  <ul class="level1">
    <li>
      <input placeholder="parent">
      <button onclick="append(2, this)">ADD</button>
      <button onclick="remove_div(this)">DEL</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="templates" id="temp2">
  <ul class="level2">
    <li>
      <input placeholder="child">
      <button onclick="append(3, this)">ADD</button>
      <button onclick="remove_div(this)">DEL</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="templates" id="temp3">
  <ul class="level3">
    <li>
      <input placeholder="sub-child">
      <button onclick="remove_div(this)">DEL</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

(I admit I like it.)

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes.It was useful.thanks.....How to do all these process dynamically.for n number of nodes??

Comment: @JasmineJoseph I'm working to improve your code. I'll update soon.

Comment: @JasmineJoseph Do you *need* the id's on the elements?

Comment: Thanks.@Takit Isy ...no need ID's

Comment: @JasmineJoseph I added my proposition of coding.

Comment: Got the code.Thank you so much.This is the method I expected.Really a Simple code that satisfied my needs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172760/discussion-between-jasmine-joseph-and-takit-isy).